# Simple file uploade error.... Why wont it work?

Tags: php, html

I have a simple file upload function, but I can't get it to work!
I keep getting and "Error" when trying to use this!

My html-file:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php'>
<input type='file' name='myfile' />
<input type='submit' value='Upload image' />
</form>
```

and my upload.php file:

```
$target = "upload_folder/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']) ; 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
echo "The file was uploaded";
} 
else {
echo "Error";
}
```

..this is one of the first times I use this, so I properly did something stupid..
Any suggestions?

Comment: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_FILES["myfile"]["error"], TRUE).'<pre>';` may give you more information.

Comment: How big is the file?  Some web servers have a size limit on uploaded files.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `method` attribute in your form. Try adding it:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method="post">
    <input type='file' name='myfile' />
    <input type='submit' value='Upload image' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods of uploading a file one is via the `POST` & other is a `PUT` request. The method your trying to use is POST. Add `method="POST"` in the form tag and it will work. 
Default in forms is to use `GET`

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method="POST" action='upload.php'>
    <input type='file' name='myfile' />
    <input type='submit' value='Upload image' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

a) File size is too big, you should change this from php.ini

b) Sometimes some servers require a more precise path for move_uploaded_file than "upload_folder/".

Let's say your php file is in the root and you want the files to go to root/upload_folder. Then do this:

```
$target = realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/upload_folder"; 
$target = $target . "/" . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

$target = "upload_folder/";

you need Write permission for target Folder or Directory.